# Ransack: how to join table multiple times with different alias?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Suppose I have :items with a has_many association with :properties, then I can search for all items that have a property with name 'a_name' and value 'a_value' like this

```
q: { properties_name_eq: 'a_name', properties_value_eq: 'a_value' }
```

Now what if I want to search for all items that have a property with name 'a_name' and value 'a_value' and also a property with name 'another_name' and value 'another_value'?

The following doesn't work as it joins the properties table only once

```
q: {
  g: {
    '0' => { properties_name_eq: 'a_name', properties_value_eq: 'a_value' },
    '1' => { properties_name_eq: 'another_name', properties_value_eq: 'another_value'}
  }
}
```

The generated SQL looks something like this

```
  SELECT DISTINCT "items".* FROM "items"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "properties" ON "properties"."item_id" = "items"."id"
  INNER JOIN ((SELECT "items".* FROM "items")) AS sel_111 on sel_111.id
  WHERE
  (("properties"."name" = 'a_name' AND "properties"."value" = 'a_value') AND ("properties"."name" = 'another_name' AND "properties"."value" = 'another_value'))
```

### EDIT:

To make it more clear what I am after, I'll paste a spec below.

```
Item.create name: 'ab', properties_attributes: [{ name: 'a', value: 'a1'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b1'}]
Item.create name: 'a', properties_attributes: [{ name: 'a', value: 'a1'}]
Item.create name: 'b', properties_attributes: [{name: 'b', value: 'b1'}]
Item.create name: 'ax', properties_attributes: [{ name: 'a', value: 'a1'}, {name: 'b', value: 'x'}]
Item.create name: 'bx', properties_attributes: [{ name: 'a', value: 'x'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b1'}]
Item.create name: 'other', properties_attributes: [{ name: 'other', value: '123'}]

get :index, q: { properties_name_eq: 'a', properties_value_eq: 'a1' }
names = JSON.parse(response.body).map{|u| u['name']}
expect(names).to match_array ['ab', 'a', 'ax'] # OK!

get :index, 
  q: {
    m: 'or',
    g: {
      '0' => { properties_name_eq: 'a', properties_value_eq: 'a1' },
      '1' => { properties_name_eq: 'b', properties_value_eq: 'b1'}
    }
  }
names = JSON.parse(response.body).map{|u| u['name']}
expect(names).to match_array ['ab'] #FAILS!
```

Comment: I have the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432074/ransack-merging-searches-on-multiple-models

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Model.search(params[:q].try(:merge, m: 'or'))`, using your example:

```
q: {
  m: 'or',
  g: {
    '0' => { properties_name_eq: 'a_name', properties_value_eq: 'a_value' },
    '1' => { properties_name_eq: 'another_name', properties_value_eq: 'another_value'}
  }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#grouping-queries-by-or-instead-of-and)

You need an `or` at the where level of your query, because properties.name can't be equal 'a_name' and 'another_name' at the same time. A second alias for the table is not required.

Comment: I definitely want an AND, but want I want to combine them using different aliases of the same table. The simple case with only 1 property name and value is working, as explained in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, we're getting closer. To clarify what I'm looking for, I added a spec to the question. Your edited code would give ["a", "ab", "ax", "b", "bx"] for the spec, so not an AND.

Comment: I get it. I've been studying this case, and didn't found a workaround yet. I let my answer here, perhaps it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using multiple queries.

1. For each name + value property, get all item IDs with this property
2. Intersect the resulting IDs for each property into `item_ids`
3. In the final query on :items, add the clause `WHERE id IN (item_ids)`

Here's a code example that does steps 1 & 2:

```
def property_item_ids(conditions)
  conditions.inject([]) do |result, (key, condition)|
    result.method(result.empty? ? '+' : '&').(Property.ransack(m: "and", g: condition).pluck(:item_id).to_a)
  end
end
```

Get the item IDs that have *all* properties:

```
conditions = {
  '0' => { properties_name_eq: 'a', properties_value_eq: 'a1' },
  '1' => { properties_name_eq: 'b', properties_value_eq: 'b1'}
}

item_ids = property_item_ids(conditions)
```

For step 3, invoke ransack with `item_ids`:

```
q: {
  m: 'and',
  g: {
    '0' => { item_id_in: item_ids }
  }
}
```