# Ransack: how to merge sub-queries?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ransack

I need to filter according to key + value in a polymorphic association. In this example, an `Incident` can have many `CustomFieldsValues`, and I need to filter `Incidents` by `CustomFieldsValue.custom_field_id` and `CustomFieldsValue.value`.

I tried creating a search like the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id FROM incidents
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT customfieldable_id from custom_fields_values
  WHERE (custom_fields_values.custom_field_id = 1091 AND (custom_fields_values.value >= '2015-06-29 10:00:00') AND (custom_fields_values.value <= '2015-07-03 09:59:59'))
)
AND id IN (
  SELECT customfieldable_id from custom_fields_values
  WHERE (custom_fields_values.custom_field_id = 1099 AND (custom_fields_values.value = 'bbb'))
);
```

Or this one with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT distinct incidents.id FROM incidents
LEFT OUTER JOIN custom_fields_values ON custom_fields_values.customfieldable_id = incidents.id AND custom_fields_values.customfieldable_type = 'Incident'
WHERE incidents.id IN (
  SELECT customfieldable_id from custom_fields_values
  WHERE (custom_fields_values.custom_field_id = 1091 AND (custom_fields_values.value >= '2015-06-29 10:00:00') AND (custom_fields_values.value <= '2015-07-03 09:59:59'))
)
AND incidents.id IN (
  SELECT customfieldable_id from custom_fields_values
  WHERE (custom_fields_values.custom_field_id = 1099 AND (custom_fields_values.value = 'bbb'))
);
```

I thought the Ransack query would look something like this:

```
Incident.ransack(:m=>"and", :g=>{
  "0"=>{"id_in"=>{
    "0"=>{:m=>"and", :g=>{
      "0"=>{"custom_fields_values_custom_field_id_is"=>1091},
      "1"=>{"custom_fields_values_value_gte_any"=>["2015-06-29 00:00:00"]},
      "2"=>{"custom_fields_values_value_lte_any"=>["2015-07-02 23:59:59"]}
    }}}},
  "1"=>{"id_in"=>{
    "0"=>{:m=>"and", :g=>{
      "0"=>{"custom_fields_values_custom_field_id_is"=>1099},
      "1"=>{"custom_fields_values_value_is_any"=>["bbb"]}
  }}}}
})
```

Is there a way to include nested queries in Ransack? I tried [merging searches](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Merging-Searches), but got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'base' for #<CustomFieldsValue::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000010fc45eb8>`.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Here's another question about the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095742/ransack-how-to-join-table-multiple-times-with-different-alias

Comment: I opened an issue in the ransack github: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/567